# Обработать ошибку подключения к БД MS SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Есть `Boolean` функция которая:

Переписана исходя из советов ниже:

```
public bool checkUser_Login(TextBox logingox)
    {
        var login = logingox.Text;
        string checklogin = $"select count(login_users) from registration where login_users = '{login}'";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand(checklogin, con))
            {
                check.Parameters.Add("login_users", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;
                int result = (int)check.ExecuteScalar();
                return result > 0;
            }                
        }
    }
```

Проверяет на совпадения в БД из `textBox` и возвращает `true`, в случае если такая запись уже есть, и соответственно `false` при отсутствии таковой. Я решил это "чудо" использовать в купе с **событием** `TextChanged`. Получил примерный код:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkUser_Login(TextBoxLogin) == true)
            {
                label2.Text = "Пользователь под ником, " + textBox1.Text + ", уже существует!";
                button1.Enabled = false;            
            }else
            {
                label2.Text = "\0";                    
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается эффект проверки **рилтайм** если login уже был зарегистрирован. Я получаю соответствующую подсказку, минуя затраты времени на использовании сначала кнопки, а после попыток исправления(про скорость работы ПО при over900000 пользователей не нужно ничего советовать, спасибо). Как обработать в данном виде исключение - `отсутствия подключения`.
Те. если сервер ***пал*** то я получу простое - `Подключение отсутствует`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что имею по итогу:

```
private async Task<bool> checkUser_Login(TextBox logingox)
        {
            var login = logingox.Text;
            string checklogin = $"select login_users from registration where login_users = '{login}'";

           
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();
                using (var check = new SqlCommand(checklogin, con))
                {
                    check.Parameters.Add("login_users", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login;
                    var result = (string)await check.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                    return result != null;
                }
            }            
        }
```

Использование:

```
bool x = await checkUser_Login(textBox1);

 if (x) {...}
```

И не забываем про async в используемом методе.

```
private async void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: MySql и Sql Server - это две **разные** СУБД. Какую именно вы используете? Не лепите какие попало метки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, поторопился, исправл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Небольшое ревью кода.
Вот это:

```
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

заменяется одной строкой:

```
return table.Rows.Count > 0;
```

---

`SqlDataAdapter` способен сам открыть и закрыть соединение и выполнить запрос.

То есть можно написать просто:

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(checklogin, connectionString);
DataTable table = new DataTable();    
adapter.Fill(table);
```

---

`SqlDataAdapter` нужен, чтобы загрузить *множество* данных в `DataTable`. Между тем, вы запрашиваете из БД одно-единственное значение.

Перепишем код на получение одного значения.
Сделаем это правильно - с применением *параметризованного запроса*.

```
private bool CheckUserLogin()
{
    string login = loginTextBox.Text;
    string checkLogin = $"select login_user from SignIN where login_user = @login";

    using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    using var command = new SqlCommand(checkLogin, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = login;

    var result = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    return result != null;
}
```

Я не знаю, какой именно тип колонки используется у вас в таблице БД. Укажите в коде соответствующий тип `SqlDbType`.

---

Более того, нет нужды возвращать из БД логин. Достаточно вернуть некое простое значение, указывающее, что юзер существует. Например:

```
string checkLogin = $"select count(login_user) from SignIN where login_user = @login";

...

int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
return result > 0;
```

---

---

А теперь, собственно, ответ на вопрос.

Используйте блок `try-catch`.
Тут может возникнуть следующая проблема: *замёрзший* интерфейс GUI в случае длительного отсутствия подсоединения к БД.
Для её решения следует использовать асинхронный код.

Что-то вроде:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckUserLoginAsync()
{
    string login = loginTextBox.Text;
    string checkLogin = $"select login_user from SignIN where login_user = @login";

    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    await using var command = new SqlCommand(checkLogin, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = login;

    var result = (string)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    return result != null;
}
```

Естественно, при вызове этого метода нужно использовать `await`.
Теперь интерфейс вашего приложения будет отзывчивым.

Comment: Единственное не могу уловить мысль с try catch, что мне вернуть в случае исключения и ошибки? Возвращая false в catch не разумно. м?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato - не надо ничто никуда возвращать. Вызов метод `CheckUserLogin` оборачиваете в `try-catch`. В `catch` выводите сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Меня немного смущает использование dB.getConnection() для получения коннекта к базе данных. Это как то "не по MS SQL-ному".

Предложу такой вариант:

Пускай у нас есть "строка подключения" (так часто переводят выражение connection string)

Тогда код, соответсвующий приведенному, будет написан примерно так:

```
    const string connStr = "Password=secret_Pa$$w0rD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbuser;Initial Catalog=DB-test;Data Source=sqlsrv,1433;";

    private Boolean checkUser_Login()
    {
        var login_user = textBox1.Text;
        string checklogin = $"select login_user from SignIN where login_user = '{login_user}'";

        
        using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr) ){
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checklogin, conn)){
                
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(table);            

                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Здесь есть одно *явное* место, где возникнет ошибка, если база данных недоступна - это строка открытия коннекта: `cn.Open()`

Теперь - давайте рассуждать.

1. Можно сделать дёшево и сердито: окружить эту конкретную строку `try-catch`-ем, и, если в ней возникает ошибка - показывать пользователю MessageBox с сообщением, что база данных недоступна.
2. Но, если подумать, это не очень хорошая стратегия. Это не так хорошо тестируется, как хотелось бы (попробуйте, протестируйте появление MessageBox - поверьте, проверить в тесте Exception - гораздо проще!)

Кроме того, при этом происходит смешивание "уровня интерфейса" (вывод сообщения) и "уровня логики".

Кроме того, пускай, connection к базе мы открыли, но возникла какая то другая ошибка.

В общем, заключить *всё* взаимодействие с базой в try-catch - это, видимо, лучше, чем обрабатывать его в функции checkUser_Login().

Но тогда понадобится добавить обарботку исключений в то место, откуда происходит вызов. Кроме того, хорошо бы добавить структурированную обработку исключений, чтобы отделить ошибку "недоступности базы" от других, менее вероятных ошибок.

Следующий шаг - это переход к асинхронному взаимодействияю с базой, ну, потому, что это возможно. И там тоже есть свои особенности того, как ведут себя исключения.

Comment: я очень слаб в MS SQL. Если есть какой-либо полезный ресурс, о котором вы знаете, я был бы признателен.

Comment: Мы можете попробовать почитать metanit ( https://metanit.com/sql/ ), но в основном - Ваш вопрос относится к языку c#, особой SQL - спецификив нём нет. я постараюсь вечером (ну, сейчас - работа) дополнить ответ законченным примером кода... И, кстати, самая идея реалтайм-проверки имени - классная

Comment: `return table.Rows.Count > 0;` :), а вообще чтобы посчитать строчки, можно использовать `ExecuteScalar()`, а запрос модифицировать вот так `select count(login_user) from`. Не придется спавнить адаптер и таблицу, из базы прилетит сразу нужное число. Правда исключение поймать придется, если в таблице ничего нет по данному запросу.

Comment: ... но это исключение в случае отсутствия данных можно вылечить SQL-функцией  COALESCE()! Совершенно правильно, постараюсь учесть это в расширенном ответе

Comment: @S.H. в общем, спустя тонны инфы и дикого интереса, я полностью перекроил подход к использованию данных БД. Он стал более MS SQL'ым, и читабельным. Вопрос открыт, я на выходных(нет) или после постараюсь так же дать более развернутый вопрос-ответ:) Пока говорю большое спасибо, но карандашом :) Ах да, я написал процедуры на стороне сервера по средствам MS SQL , и при помощи c# обращаюсь к ним при необходимости. Такой подход мне показался более удобный и безопасный. Времени совсем не осталось, надеюсь на выходных(нет) я разверну вопрос.